# Drupal7: Linked template node file

Tags: theming

How I can define my node-title.tpl.php via dashboard?

Here what I did:

1. I created new content type page (our locations)
2. I uploaded a file to the templates: node-our-locations.tpl.php
3. I added new (our locations) content, and I set (our locations) in the title field

Comment: plz expand details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the page about [Drupal 7 Template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) - you would see that the proper template suggestions for Drupal 7 nodes are :

- `node--NODEID.tpl.php`
- `node--NODETYPE.tpl.php`

I'm unsure from your question whether you want a template for a particular node (in which case you should use the node id, not the node title - `node--NODEID.tpl.php`) or for all nodes of your content type "our locations" (in which case you want to use the second form, which depends on the node type, not the node title, `node--NODETYPE.tpl.php`)

Note that NODETYPE is your content type's machine name - on your site you will see this next to the content type name when you go to "admin/structure/types", and that hyphens should be replaced by underscores. So if your content type machine name was `our-locations`, the template file you want is `node--our_locations.tpl.php`)

Finally remember that once you've added the new template file, you must clear your cache before it gets noticed. You can do this on the performance page on your site at "admin/config/development/performance".

Comment: thank you so much, also I added some code to the page.tpl.php and now it work